# jQuery CSS and .hover() not picking up style

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery to add `.hover` class to list items.

```
$("#list .item").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Then followed by the style in jQuery (I have to supply the style in JS)

```
$('#list .item.hover').css('padding-left', '20px');
```

The hover class is being applied but the style is not picked up?

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but I think it's only IE6 that doesn't support the :hover css pseudo-class on non-anchor elements.  I don't know what your requirements are but we dropped support for IE6 months ago as its usage is now less than 5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up style sheets with styles applied to the elements. The jQuery code in your second code block doesn't create a style sheet rule that will apply when the class is added to the element, it applies the style to elements that has the class at the moment that the code is executed.

If you want the style to kick in when you add the class to the element, it has to be a rule in a style sheet. Alternatively you could just change the style in the hover event handlers:

```
$("#list .item").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css('padding-left', '20px');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css('padding-left', '');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS for this :)

```
.item:hover { 
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

No jQuery/JavaScript needed :)

When you use a selector, it finds elements matching that selector **at that time** and runs the rest of the chain on them, it doesn't create new CSS style rules in the background or anything, you need to define these styles in CSS.

If you do need to use a hover class for some other reason, you can do this:

```
$("#list .item").hover(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

But you should stick with CSS and `:hover` in this case :)

Comment: Hi Nick, don't you need the hover class for this to work in IE, since I thought `:hover` only worked on links? So why not use both? And wouldn't just adding this CSS work? `.item:hover, .item.hover { padding-left: 20px; }`

Comment: @fudgey: If you need to support IE6 yes, but I wouldn't do that...it *works*, you just don't get a bell/whistle in a decade old browser :) Why make every *other* browser slower in order to support IE6?  If you're in that position I understand, but most of the time it's ok to leave out styling as long as the functionality is all there.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#list .item:hover').css('padding-left', '20px');
```

:hover is a psuedo-class.

Comment: This is exactly how it should be done, altho i would look at hover(in(),out());

Comment: `:hover` is not a [valid selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), think about how it's used as I note in my answer, that's why it's not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're adding the styling through javascript?  I bet this works perfectly if you do it through css.

What I'm guessing is happening is that you're adding/removing the class hover, which works, but when the:

```
$('#list .item.hover').css('padding-left', '20px');
```

happens, none of those classes actually have a class of hover (at that time).  That declaration doesn't persist for all items that get .hover added to them after the fact.

Again, put the style in css

Answer (score 0):

Your `.hover` class may be declared incorrectly in the style:

```
#list .item .hover
{
   /*
     won't be applied when <element class='item hover'/>,
     only when <element class='item'><sub-element class='hover'/></element>
   */
}

#list .item.hover
{
   /*
     will be applied when <element class='item hover'/>,
     but not when <element class='item'><sub-element class='hover'/></element>
   */
}
```